# New PC can't power on

Tags: boot, desktop-computer, repair

I set up a new PC recently and when I try to power on, it doesn't even start - the motherboard LEDs are on. I do not know what exactly I did wrong can anyone help me?

**What I see and noticed**

- When I hit / press the power on button it flash ones and then it doesn't do anything.
- Not even fans are starting rotating, but as I state motherboard LED is still on.

**Specifications**

1. `Asus 970` gaming
2. PSU core stream 500w
3. 16 GB RAM DDR3

Comment: Double check the power supply connections - Try another PSU - report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with the power supply. If power were able to get to the motherboard you'd have fans working and likely some number of beeps depending on the issue. Swap out the PSU and see if the problem persists.

Comment: thank you man power supply wasnt working for unknwon reason i brought a new one and its perfect

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach.

1. Is the cable not lose? (Double Check The connectors / connections)
2. Try another outlet.
3. Try another PSU or Test Your PSU to other PC.
4. Check for pins connections (power pins).
5. If it beeps, how many `Long Beeps` or `Short Beeps` ?

**From what said -  double check especially this with highlight (This might not your actual MB but hope give you some idea.)**

[image: mb]

**`Note: For the front panel headers, look for the model of your MB and search for the slots - corresponds to your pins (From your System case).`**

For your PSU, if it's functioning, the Fan is working (normally - not too slow / pause for a minute) then probably your connectors / connections is the problem.

Comment: Hello ther e is no way that has to do with cpu wrong instalatio althout im sure i dint u just try to take thins out also cause i have ninja syth cooler and it was fiting i change the site of the motherboard backplate so that i can connect the screws that hold the cooler otherwise it was unstable do you thing has something with this

Comment: Are you the one who assembled it? Or when you bought that one it's already fixed - package?

If you just bought that one a couple of days / weeks ago, support is still available / warranty. You can contact them for maybe - still they offer free checkup. If the seal is not broken.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

1. turn off the pc
2. Remove power cable
3. Now hold the power button for 1 minute
4. Plug back the power cable
5. Now turn on the PC. 
   Hope this will help.